# make lines reach to the left border in html and css

Tags: html, css

newbie for CSS here.  I tried make lines reachingto the far left. After running my code, there are still some distance to the left border.  I have no idea why it happens.  Below is my html, css code and the snapshot of my running result.  Hope you could help me out.  Thanks.

```css
#strings li {
  height: 1px;
  width: 60%;
  margin: 20px;
  background: #f00;
  list-style-type: none;
  left:0px;
  float:left;
  position:relative;
}
```

```html
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="code.css">

<body>
  <ul id="strings">
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
  </ul>
</body>
```

Result after running my code:
[image]

Comment: Replace `margin: 20px` with `margin: 20px 0;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ul` has default padding assigned to it. Set `padding:0;` to `ul` element will fix it.

```
#strings{
    padding:0;
}
```

If you want to reduce the margin further you can change your existing margin styling of `li` element.

```
#strings li {
    height: 1px;
    width: 60%;
    margin: 20px 0; // this will set margin from top/bottom and set it 0 from left/right
    background: #f00;
    list-style-type: none;
    left:0px;
    float:left;
    position:relative;
}
```

[Working Example](https://jsfiddle.net/m2v7z4ag/)

Answer (score 0):

```
#strings li {
    height: 1px;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 20px 0px;
    background: #f00;
    list-style-type: none;
    left:0px;
    float:left;
    position:relative;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I just gave you concise solution:

```
#strings li {
    height: 1px;
    width: 60%;
    margin: 20px 0; *// you put 0 to margin for both side margin*
    background: #f00;
    list-style-type: none;
    left:0px;
    float:left;
    position:relative;
}
```